# How to scroll to index in infinite list with react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have an infinite list (using components `InfiniteLoader` and `List` from the awesome `react-virtualized` library). I want to scroll to a specific row to respond to a user generated event.

This is my code :

```
class Weeks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      week_count: 10,
    }
    auto_bind(this)
  }

  is_week_loaded(week) {
    return week < this.state.week_count
  }

  load_more_weeks() {
    this.setState({week_count: this.state.week_count + 1})
  }

  scroll_to_week(week) {
    if (this.state.week_count <= week) {
      this.setState({week_count: week + 1})
    }
    this.list.scrollToRow(week)
  }

  render_week({key, index, style}) {
    return (
      <div key={key} style={style}>
        <Week week={index}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AutoSizer>
        {({height, width}) => (
          <InfiniteLoader
            isRowLoaded={this.is_week_loaded}
            loadMoreRows={this.load_more_weeks}
            rowCount={this.state.week_count + 1}
            >
            {({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) => (
              <List
                height={height}
                width={width}
                onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                ref={(list) => {
                  this.list = list
                  registerChild(list)
                }}
                rowCount={this.state.week_count}
                rowHeight={row_height}
                rowRenderer={this.render_week}
                />
            )}
          </InfiniteLoader>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    )
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.list.scrollToRow is not a function
```

when I call the `scroll_to_week` method.

I thought from the documentation https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/reverseList.md that it was the correct way to scroll to a row index.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: shouldn't it be this.refs.list.scrollToRow() ?

Comment: @Chase, when you provide a string to the ref prop, it is indeed the correct way, but here I'm providing a function. This function is called before `componentDidMount` is called. I have used it to define `this.list`.

Answer (score 2):

`scrollToRow` is a prop, not a function. =)

Try this:

```
class Weeks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      week_count: 10,
    }
    auto_bind(this)
  }

  is_week_loaded(week) {
    return week < this.state.week_count
  }

  load_more_weeks() {
    this.setState({week_count: this.state.week_count + 1})
  }

  scroll_to_week(week) {
    if (this.state.week_count <= week) {
      this.setState({
        scroll_to_week: week,
        week_count: week + 1
      })
    }
  }

  render_week({key, index, style}) {
    return (
      <div key={key} style={style}>
        <Week week={index}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AutoSizer>
        {({height, width}) => (
          <InfiniteLoader
            isRowLoaded={this.is_week_loaded}
            loadMoreRows={this.load_more_weeks}
            rowCount={this.state.week_count + 1}
            >
            {({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) => (
              <List
                height={height}
                width={width}
                onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                ref={(list) => {
                  registerChild(list)
                }}
                rowCount={this.state.week_count}
                rowHeight={row_height}
                rowRenderer={this.render_week}
                scrollToRow={this.state.scroll_to_week}
                />
            )}
          </InfiniteLoader>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What about if I want to scroll back to the same week ? Let's say I have a button that scrolls to the current day. The user can scroll anywhere, and then tap the button, which calls scroll_to_week. scrollToRow isn't changed, so List won't update. Or does it update every time ? in that case, it will be impossible for the user to scroll away from the row given as scrollToRow. I really believe you cannot have a consistent behaviour if it's a prop, because the component cannot be the reflection of its props at all times.

Comment: RV uses "pure" components so they won't re-render if props don't change. This is a limitation of the pure props approach for scroll-to-index. Best current work-around is to set that prop to `undefined` in between so that it changes.

Comment: Should we create an issue for that ? I can make a Pull request for that if you want.

Comment: I intentionally removed `scrollToCell` type API methods several versions ago. Ideally React components should be controlled through props. API methods _require_ refs and are kind of awkward to work with by comparison.

In addition to my previously-mentioned concerns, I also don't like supporting multiple ways to do a thing (as it makes maintenance more complicated).

I saw your request come through already. I'm not sure if I'll accept it or not. Need to think about it some.

Comment: I've updated my issue to carry on this conversation : https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/511. Also if you don't intend to change the API, at least correct the documentation (the link I gave in the issue)